# Android JSON Parsing | PHP Scripts and Validate JSON

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I have a database in phpmyadmin panel. And I want to see this databases as json format. When I paste my link to http://jsonlint.com/. It says Null. What's wrong with my php script?

```
<?php

$host = "**";
$user = "**";
$password = "**";
$db = "**";

$sql = "select * from product_info;";
$con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$db);

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$response = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    array_push($response,array("name"=>$row[0],"email"=>$row[1],"mobile"=>$row[2]));
}

echo json_encode(array("server_response"=>$respose));
mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a letter in the word "response" on the echo line. That's why you are getting NULL.

**Replace**

```
echo json_encode(array("server_response"=>$respose));
```

**By this**

```
echo json_encode(array("server_response"=>$response));
```

---

Also, you should set the header to **application/json**

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

**Final code should be:**

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');

echo json_encode(array("server_response"=>$response));
```

Comment: It's working now. Thank you very much for your attention. I have a question. Is there any PHP compiler for this spelling errors?

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo (`$respose`) in the line

```
echo json_encode(array("server_response"=>$respose));
```

which should be

```
echo json_encode(array("server_response"=>$response));
```